# Implement Many to Many with Django (No duplicates)

Tags: django, django-models

There is a table that has lob(one-to-many field) each lob is mapped to 1 or more client, so there is another table called client(many-to-many).
Basically once you select a lob an ajax call is made and the related clients are fetched and displayed on the template

```
client = models.ManyToManyField(Client)
lob    = models.ForeignKey(
         LoB, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
         null=True
         )
```

Now there needs to change lob to  many-to-many, but the issue is a client can be mapped to more than one lob, so once multiple lobs are selected it would end up showing duplicate clients.
Any ideas how to handle this!

**Tables**

> **lob**
>   -->Testing
>   -->Developing
>   -->Designing
>
> **client**
>   -->US
>   -->IND
>   -->AFRICA
>
> **client-lob** 
>   Testing-->US 
>   Testing-->IN 
>   Designing-->IN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.

```
queryset = queryset.values('client').distinct()   # this is your queryset
clients = Client.objects.filter(id__in=queryset)
```

Then serialize the clients queryset.